# convox docker build is very slow

Tags: convox

I have a gen3 AWS rack.

My convox build is very slow. (30 minutes+)

I am using a custom docker file in my convox.yml to build my services.

When I run `convox build` I can see that the docker image is being built from scratch without any docker layer caching.

My rack node_type is `t3.large`

Is there something I can configure in convox to make my builds faster/ enable layer caching?

Answer (score 0):

How many instances are in your Rack?  On v3, the build can happen on a random instance, and unfortunately the docker cache is not shared between them so if you build on a 'new' instance, with no cache, then it will take longer.  If you build on an instance that's previously had a build then it should re-use the layer cache from before.
Convox is actively looking into utilising buildx and it's options to open up more build options and quicker builds so keep an eye out for that!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I have 9 instances in the prod rack at the moment, but that can scale a bit at times.

It would be great to be able to stick the builds to an instance so I can hit the cache.

:)